# CoordinatorLayout error after updating to Android 3.0.1

Tags: android, xml, preview

[image]

[image]

Just after updating my Android Studio 2.4 to 3.0, I started getting this issue. The preview of the XML files are not showing (it used to work perfectly all right in earlier version).

Moreover, once playing with "File>Project Structure>App>Incremental Dex ... with values "blank", "true" and "false", the preview once came, but again blacked out with "android...CoordinatorLayout".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also struggling with this error "android...Coordinator Layout" and "Failed to instantiate one or more classes".

I tried these many "failed" attempts: 1. Changing API level in design tab of any XML file. 2. Changing design theme 3. installing newest SDK files etc etc.

But finally after few sleepless night I was able to do it by: 1. Un-installing the complete Android Studio and SDK downloaded files. [NOTE: this also helped me in saving precious space in my 120GB MAC book] 2. Installing default SDK files as prompted during installation. 3. Changing a little in my "build.gradel" file. "Compiles SDK version", "target SDK version" and "dependencies" all has the same level. [26 in my case; my min SDK was 15]

And this again given me error after syncing gradle. But It showed some error [something with MAVEN...kind of forgotten to take the snapshot of that error] and I just downloaded that extra file required for the same.

And then, IT WORKED.

NOTE: Let me make it clear that, I am basically a Mechanical Engineer and trying to make my app for the benefits of Mechanical Engineers " Mechanical Engineering Total".

Comment: Minor Edit: "And this again given me error after syncing gradle. But It showed some error [something with MAVEN...kind of forgotten to take the snapshot of that error] and I just downloaded that extra file required for the same."  After checking my error log, its something related to " *daemon not started". I started it by the link suggested in the error log and things became smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Please update SDK and try again.
[image]

Comment: Hi Akhil MG, I updated my SDK as well... still the problem continues.

Comment: I even tried uninstalling complete Android studio and SDK files. And then agains installed everything from scratch. Still this "android...coordinator layout" error persists.  Pls help [F1]